# How to check Openshift HAProxy Router set timeout value

Tags: openshift

How to check the current timout value of the haproxy.router.openshift.io/timeout in openshift environment.

Comment: Have you checked the default project? That's where the router runs.

Comment: yes, I have don't see the property. I don't know where to check.

Comment: I think that the default is 30 seconds but I cannot recall where I saw that

Answer (score 1):

`haproxy.router.openshift.io/timeout` can be set on a per-`Route` basis, see the documentation: [Configuring route timeouts](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/networking/routes/route-configuration.html#nw-configuring-route-timeouts_route-configuration).

So you can check your annotations on your Route by using the following commands:

```
# List all Routes
oc get routes -o yaml
# List a particular Route
oc get route <route-name> -o yaml
```

You will then see the annotations listed under "`metadata`":

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  annotations:
    haproxy.router.openshift.io/timeout: 2s
[..]
```